# What choice of naming for this kind of units?

Tags: .net, grammar

[EDIT]
The question was a bit over-explained.

Cumulative
Consumption
Instantaneous
Average

What would you name this kind of units?
The listed options is used to specify how to calculate values in a table.

I.e.
Cumulative = 53 (sum of all)
Consumption = 8 (gap between two values)
Instantaneous = 20 (at asked time)
Average = 13,25 (sum 53/4 values)


The question is only for me to make a clear and understandable naming convention in the system.

Comment: Please show us, how you use it.

Comment: It could be a name of an ENUM, database table or a .NET datatype which should hold it's data (list of values) together with this info.

Comment: Sorry, I don't seem to understand how the enum and those dates relate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call them *aggregates* or *reductions* of the data. In all cases, you're taking a bunch of data and summarizing it by computing one number. Other words that can be used are *measure*, *statistic* and *digest*.

Comment: Aggregation works. If it was allowed AggregateMethod would work. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

I would name it `CalculationMode`, because it is "used to specify how to calculate values in a table".